# How to prevent duplicate insertion when F5 is pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In the below code iam doing functionalities for inserting values in db.Everything is working fine but the thing is if I press F5 or Ctrl+F5 the page is reloaded and the same values are inserting once again. I just emptied the text box values but it isn't working.How to prevent duplicate insertion..

Thanks in Advance.

```
 protected void btnAddNewQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Usp_insertNewQuestion", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@AppID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = applicationId;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TenantID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Questions", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtNewQuestion.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuestionType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlNewQuestionType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@AudioPath", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtNewAudioPath.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuestionStatus", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Int32.Parse(rdoNewQuestionStatus.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DataType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlNewQuestionDataType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserField", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlNewUserField.Text;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Response.Write(err.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

            //string type = Page.Request.Form["hdnAddQuestionField"].ToString();
           // if (type == "Security Question")
            //    getSecurityQuestions();
            //if (type == "Personal Identity")
            //    getPersonalIdentityQuestions();
            //if (type == "Past History")
           //     getPastHistoryQuestions();

            txtNewQuestion.Text = string.Empty;
            ddlNewQuestionType.Text = string.Empty;
            txtNewAudioPath.Text =string.Empty;
            rdoNewQuestionStatus.SelectedItem.Value = string.Empty;
            ddlNewQuestionDataType.Text = string.Empty;
            ddlNewUserField.Text = string.Empty;


        }
```

Answer (score 2):

A way to avoid this problem is redirecting after post to the same page (`Response.Redirect("[current_url]")`). This pattern is known as PRG (Post/Redirect/Get). In this way, browser refresh will cause a GET after your POST, avoiding those problematic duplicated submissions.

More details about this pattern [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)